# Manage wait cursor for task

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, griffon, groovyfx

1. I'm outside the UI and wish to display a wait cursor while stuff is
   happening and using this basic pattern:

   `on UI - primaryStage.scene.cursor = Cursor.WAIT 
   try {
   do stuff off UI...
   } finally {
   on UI - primaryStage.scene.cursor = Cursor.DEFAULT
   }`

While running I can start another process which completes quickly and the Cursor is restored before the first task completes.

I don't mind "waiting" while the first task completes, but I don't think this means doing the work on the UI thread? 
Is there any built in solution for this pattern provided in javafx?

2. My tab contains 2 Combo Box. When I hit the 2nd Combo Box drop down, a WAIT cursor sometimes appears over the list even though the Cursor is currently DEFAULT state. If I move the mouse pointer outside/back on the list the cursor is correctly displayed as Default. Would this be a separate issue or somehow related?

VIEW

```
label 'From'
comboBox(items: bind(model.wcomboFromItemsProperty()), value: bind(model.wcomboFromProperty()), selectFromAction)
label 'To'
comboBox(items: bind(model.wcomboFromItemsProperty()), value: bind(model.wcomboToProperty()), selectToAction)
```

MODEL

```
@FXObservable ListElement wcomboFrom = new ListElement()
@FXObservable ListElement wcomboTo = new ListElement()
@FXObservable List wcomboFromItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList()
@FXObservable List wcomboToItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList()

final ObjectProperty<Cursor> CURSOR_DEFAULT = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Cursor.DEFAULT)
final ObjectProperty<Cursor> CURSOR_WAIT = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Cursor.WAIT)
```

CONTROLLER

```
//lifecycle
void onReadyStart(GriffonApplication application) {
    loadWindowData()
}

// both combo boxes contain the same items
protected void loadWindowData() {
    def list = [new ListElement(textValue: '')]
    list.addAll dataService.getData().collect {
        new ListElement(textValue: it.name, objectValue: it)
    }

    runInsideUIAsync {
        model.wcomboFromItems.addAll(list)
        model.wcomboToItems.addAll(list)
    }
}

void selectFrom() {
    performAction {
        gcListFrom = getControlList(model.wcomboFrom.objectValue)
        setTreeItems(model.wtreeGcFrom, gcListFrom, model.wcomboFrom)
        setTreeItems(model.wtreeGcTo, gcListTo, model.wcomboTo)
    }
}

void selectTo() {
    performAction {
        gcListTo = getControlList(model.wcomboTo.objectValue)
        setTreeItems(model.wtreeGcTo, gcListTo, model.wcomboTo)
    }
}

def performAction = {c ->
    Task<Void> t = new Task() {
        @Override protected Void call() {
            println "Running closure " + isUIThread()
            c.call()
        }
    }

    runInsideUISync {
        application.primaryStage.scene.cursorProperty().bind(Bindings.when(t.runningProperty())
            .then(model.CURSOR_WAIT).otherwise(model.CURSOR_DEFAULT))
    }

    runOutsideUI(t)
}
```

OTHER

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = 'textValue')
class ListElement implements Serializable {
    String textValue = ""
    Serializable objectValue // Serializable object from business model

    @Override
    String toString() {
        textValue
    }
}
```

The Griffon framework automatically invokes the onAction controller events outside the UI thread. GroovyFX contains some magic which adds an "onSelect" action bound to selectionModel.selectedItemProperty i.e.

```
class GroovyFXEnhancer {
    static void enhanceClasses() {
        ...
        ComboBox.metaClass {
            cellFactory << { Closure closure -> delegate.setCellFactory(closure as Callback)}
            onSelect << { Closure closure ->
                delegate.selectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener(closure as ChangeListener);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running rdesktop from Linux to Windows 7 so might be something weird. Main issue for now is a effective wait indicator pattern...I'm thinking a counter so cursor default is only restored once counter is back to zero

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any built in solution for this pattern provided in javafx?

I would advice you to use the built in [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) ;)

It has predefined methods to handle everything you need.

```
private Task<Void> backgroundTask = new Task() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        // Something to do on background thread ;
        return null;
    }
};
```

It has a [runningProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#runningProperty--), which can bind to the [cursorProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#cursorProperty--) of the scene.

You can create two `ObjectProperty<Cursor>` containing `Cursor.DEFAULT` and `CURSOR.WAIT`.

```
final ObjectProperty<Cursor> CURSOR_DEFAULT = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Cursor.DEFAULT);
final ObjectProperty<Cursor> CURSOR_WAIT = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Cursor.WAIT);
```

Then you can bind them to the task :

```
scene.cursorProperty().bind(Bindings.when(backgroundTask.runningProperty())
                                            .then(CURSOR_WAIT).otherwise(CURSOR_DEFAULT));
```

> Would this be a separate issue or somehow related?

If your action on the ComboBox is somehow invoking the background thread, then it might be related, else it is difficult to comment.

Comment: Binding the cursor to the task's running property would be preferred - you don't want the cursor not to be returned to the default if the the task errors.

Comment: thanks - I'll come back and mark this. 2. I handle single selection events on both Combos. I select new item on the 1st combo, then while Cursor=WAIT I do same on 2nd combo.  They both finish successfully and Cursor=DEFAULT. Then I click on 2nd combo (before I select anything) and the Cursor shows WAIT. Since both tasks completed and cursor went back to DEFAULT, I'm unsure why 2nd combo showed WAIT at all. But as the pattern is flawed I'm just interested in why it did that - perhaps a javafx bug but more likely an undesired outcome due to bad user code :)

Comment: @shnplr You still haven't explained anything about what makes the cursor change when you select an item on the combobox. Some code snippets would be really helpful.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha - I've created a standalone gist which successfully reproduces both issues running IDEA 14.1.3 (JDK 1.8.0_45 64bit) - https://gist.github.com/shnplr/32b2720f5ba3ad27d963

Comment: @shnplr Can you post a link to the gist?

Comment: I just [updated your GIST](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/06bdf4ad3039616834a1) with a proper binding. Seems like a bug to me. Could you please report it to the [JavaFX bug tracker](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/), so that the developers could have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `griffon-tasks-plugin` http://griffon-plugins.github.io/griffon-tasks-plugin/

This plugin delivers and UI toolkit agnostik SwingWorker-like API for executing tasks in a background thread.