# Change cursor without concurrency

Tags: multithreading, javafx, cursor, task, sequential

As far as I understand it you need to change the cursor in the `call()` method of a `Task` to be able to change the cursor properly. But in my application, I press a button and do something. And I do not want the application do to anything before this is done. I just want to inform the user that the the application is loading by changing the cursor.

Problem is that if I start a separate thread for the task, the rest of the program doesn't wait for that task to succeed. And if I put it in the same thread as the application (I guess that's what I'm doing), by doing `Platform.runLater(task)`, the cursor doesn't change.

The method that is called when I press the button is a void method, so that prevents me from putting the return statement inside the tasks `setOnSucceeded()` method.

The optimal scenario would be if I could just do this:

```
//app.getPrimaryStage() returns the application stage.

void method () throws InterruptedException {
    app.getPrimaryStage().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

    // Simulate execution of code that takes some time
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    app.getPrimaryStage().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

}
```

Or just create a task and execute it in the current thread, like this:

```
//app.getPrimaryStage() returns the application stage.

void method () throws InterruptedException {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        protected Void call() {
            app.getPrimaryStage().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

            // Simulate execution of code that takes some time
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            app.getPrimaryStage().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

            return null;
        }
    }; 

    Platform.runLater(task);  
}
```

But none of these methods work. I can see that the cursor is changing "underneath" by doing this: `app.getPrimaryStage().getScene().cursorProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> { System.out.println(newValue); });` But the change isn't showing unless I run the task in a separate thread. Why is this? And what is the best way to force the program to wait for a task that is run by a separate thread?

Comment: "I start a separate thread for the task, the rest of the program doesn't wait for that task to succeed", you can do this. Check [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).

Comment: Additionaly, why are you executing the Task on `Platform.runLater`?

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll check it out. Regarding your question, I got the impression that Platform.runLater would run it on application thread.

Comment: You might want to also want to bind the `runningProperty()` of the Task to the to the cursors. For more information, you can go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30619332/1759128).

Comment: *"As far as I understand it you need to change the cursor in the call() method of a Task to be able to change the cursor properly."* That's not correct. In fact, if you run the task in a background thread, which is what tasks are generally used for, you *must not* do this, as you must not change the UI from a background thread. Running the task on the FX Application thread using `Platform.runLater(...)` just makes the task redundant.

Answer (score 3):

There are two rules about multithreading in JavaFX you need to follow:

1. Changes to the UI **must** be performed on the FX Application Thread
2. Long-running tasks **must not** be performed on the FX Application Thread

Typically, you should use a `Task` to execute code on a background thread, i.e. not on the FX Application Thread.

Both your blocks of code violate the second rule: the first because you call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the FX Application Thread directly. In the second block of code, you place that call in a `Task`, but then explicitly execute the task on the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater(...)`, which makes it (more or less) equivalent to the first block (i.e. it makes the task redundant).

Your basic premise is wrong: you do not want to "block the program" by blocking execution of the FX Application thread. This will make the UI unresponsive and prevent any UI  updates (like changing the cursor) from actually happening. You should "block the program" by disabling it (or portions of it), and reenabling it when your task completes.

So you want something like:

```
void method() {
    Scene scene = app.getPrimaryStage().getScene();
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void call() throws Exception {

            // Simulate execution of code that takes some time
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            return null ;
        }
    };

    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        scene.getRoot().setDisable(false);
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    });

    scene.getRoot().setDisable(true);
    scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

    Thread t = new Thread(task);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```